# Decoding Message-Signature Pairs

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory, cryptography

I've been given a set of message-signature pairs to decrypt using a public RSA key I set up. I need to sort through the decoded messages, and find which of those have a valid signature. My public key is

```
e=13
```

and

```
m=23988477718194197355263570318118557072073635564327068738051383543307247873821867
```

My code so far comprises of

```
decryptionRSA[x_?IntegerQ, d_?IntegerQ, m_?IntegerQ] := PowerMod[x, d, m]; 
SetAttributes[decryptionRSA, Listable]
messages2 = Table[i -> decryptionRSA[messages, d, m], {i, messages}]
```

It then outputs `messages2`, which is too big to copy onto here. Note that: `d=PowerMod[e,-1,m]`. A message signature pair will come in the form (a,b), with b being the signature. To tell if the pair is valid and authentic, using the public key, you compute `z=PowerMod[b,e,m]` and if this equal to a then the pair is valid. However, I don't know how I would verify this with a large quantity of data, would I use the `Table` function?

Answer (score 1):

This answer will try to address a number of shortcomings/inconsistencies in the body of the question and finally suggest a possible solution.

### Issues

1. In the definition of the function `decryptionRSA[]` the second parameter, namely parameter `d`, is not an **actual** parameter. According to the body of text, `d=PowerMod[e,-1,m]`, where `e` and `m` are given.
2. Assigning the attribute `Listable` to symbol `decryptionRSA` will allow it to thread over lists. Applying a `listable` function over a list of pairs eg `f[{{a,1},{b,2},...}]` does not produce `{f[a,1],f[b,2],...}` which is the desirable behavior, but rather `{{f[a],f[1]},{f[b],f[2]},...}`.

### A solution

Assuming that `messages` is a list containing pairs of *message* and *signature*, then the following code will produce a list of booleans, where `True` would indicate the position of a valid pair *in the original list*.

```
d = PowerMod[e,-1,m]
mask = Map[(
  #[[1]] == PowerMod[#[[2]], d, m] 
 )&,messages]
```

The valid pairs can be retrieved using eg `pos = Position[mask,True]` and then `valids = Extract[messages,pos]`.